# Apply a sum to a worksheet of values ​that are in other workbook sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I want to apply a sum to a spreadsheet that is open, but the values ​​are in other spreadsheets that are inside the workbook, in Plan 01, 02, 03 has values ​​to be summed that are in cell "A1" of all of them. How do I add these values ​​to just one spreadsheet?

[image]

Comment: Simply point to the cell/range on another worksheet using mouse. Excel will build correct reference by himself, something like `Sheet2!A1:B2` or `[Book2]Sheet2!$A$1:$B$2`.

Comment: Not possible, it would take too long if it were about 20 spreadsheets. I need VBA code that offers the option to open the files in the folder and then apply the sum to all of them.

Comment: My comment shown how to look at correct referenced address syntax. Use this knowledge in your VBA code...

Comment: I don't really know VBA, I know very little. That's why I need help kkkk. I'm having trouble even using Excel's own matrix formulas, now imagine VBA